# AngularUI: modals, resolve and controller's locals (how to pass a model to a modal controller)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Whatever I try to do I can't seem to pass data to a modal controller.

I tried using resolve:

```
   var opts = {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        backdropClick: true,
        templateUrl:  'views/details/basic/view.html',
        controller: 'BoxDetailsCtrl'
        resolve: {
            item: function () {
                return angular.copy(item)
            },
            price: function (){ return 100; }
        }

        this.d = this.d || $dialog.dialog($scope.opts);
        this.d.open();
```

I tried passing the scope:

```
     var opts = {
        scope: $scope
        ...
```

In my dispair I event tried hacking the dialog service:

```
 if (self.options.controller) {
                    var ctrl = $controller(self.options.controller, locals);
                    ctrl.modal = self.options.modal; // nasty hack
                    self.modalEl.children().data('ngControllerController', ctrl);
           }
```

Nothing worked. I can't seem to be able to pass data to BoxDetailsCtrl. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Comment: I'm struggling through a similar problem and found your unanswered question. It might help if you include the instantiation of BoxDetailsCtrl in your question. I'm having problems passing locals to a controller declared with Module.controller(...) and I think it has to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

This method is working for me ... it's in coffeescript but you can convert it to js.

[AngularUI separate files for modal controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840713/angularui-separate-files-for-modal-controllers)

```
resolve:
       primer3: ->
         $scope.primer3
```

Then

```
angular.module('assaypipelineApp').controller "ConfigureModalCtrl", ($scope,  $modalInstance, primer3) ->
  $scope.primer3 = primer3['data']
```

I found I was getting an object with the data array embedded and with the http return code. I don't really understand why, but this works.

I hope that helps.